# will i face any problems on body building

Tags: bodybuilding

I am 5.5 feet, 71kg, waist 32 and my stomatch is out. I recently joined gym and the trainer tells me that we will put on more weight on the upper part like on chest and biceps so when the biceps becomes like 20 inch then we can cut it by work outs and it will stop at 15-16 inches and will be very hard like stone. Is this the right way of body building??? Will i not face the problem of being over weight???? 
Will i get abs and biceps i wanted ?? 
Is trainer going the right way ??? Please answer me asap. I am really worried .very worried.

Comment: 20 inches?  I'd get a new trainer if I were you.  Sounds like he's leading you down the wrong path.  Make sure he's a certified trainer.

Comment: Actually he didnt mean 20 but he told me to put on some weight on the upper portion so we can cut the fat out . Is he doing alright?

Comment: Just as you can't spot reduce, you can't add weight onto a specific part of your body.  If you add more calories, the weight will be distributed throughout your body.  Again, I'd ask him if he's certified as a trainer, and, if so, what is the organization so you check if it's reputable.

Comment: Well, you can add more weight/volume to spots, but it involves injecting cooking oil and it's a really bad idea...

Comment: I think the trainer's logic here is: "we're going to add mass to your frame, but I don't care how much is fat or muscle. Once total arm size (fat and muscle) is 20 inches, we'll have you cut until your arm size is 15-16 inches." Sounds like he's advocating a dirty bulk before cutting.

Comment: Yes he told the same. That he will start cutting after putting on some muscle on it. So it could stop at 16-17 inches ..

Comment: And what will i have to do for my abs ???

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to set up a healthy diet and work to build muscle and burn off the weight you currently have on your waist. There is no need to go "off season" per say when you are just starting out. You don't have enough muscle mass to get rid of it efficiently. There are many bodybuilders who don't even add any more to their calorie intake but just to maintain, but that's further down the road. For now, stick with a healthy diet and weight train and get to know what works with your body. One exercise can work at one point than not at another. The challenge is to get past your body getting used to a muscle building activity and pulling out another exercise to get it to grow a little bit more. Keep in mind, that we can reach a great physic naturally without resorting to unnatural ways of doing it. So, we may not turn into Ronnie Coleman but you will still feel bigger and this time, it will not be your stomach.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty similar dimensions, but bulked up nicely a few years back and have a couple of thoughts:

Your trainer's advice sounds good for rapid bodybuilding, but not for what it sounds like you want (toned body, flat tummy, etc).  If he's telling you to do a bicep curl, then drop him and prepare to spend several weekends reading way too much conflicting advice online :)

Muscle burns fat, so if you want to lose fat, it doesn't hurt to do some hypertrophy to build muscles quickly.  However, I wouldn't focus too much on dimensions.  Your biceps are tiny things compared to the legs/core/back, so building them up will achieve next to nothing in terms of burning fat.  Focus on core (deadlifts, squats, freeweights etc), functional training, and as an added bonus you will go into middle age (or further) with a body thats built to work.  Trust me, that gets pretty important.

Building abs is frankly impossible.  What you need to do is lose fat.  This is as much diet as anything else.  Once you've built up a good base of muscle, and are moderately fit, shift your focus onto high-intensity sprints, a good clean diet, avoid beers & milk etc.  Drink more water, whatever your doing is not enough.  I also found tabata sprints did wonders for me, as did a short spurt of going vegan, but you will probably need to experiment to find out is needed at each plateau to keep you going.  Also - try to measure your bodyfat (you can get passable bodyfat callipers for about $30), and forget the scales.

tldr;  Do a functional workout, get a flat stomach, forget your biceps.  By the time you have the tummy, the biceps will look great anyway.  Also remember, the faster it comes, the faster it goes.  Don't look for miracles, and even after a long winter in front of the computer you'll still be able to flex and find your 6-pack.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment of your answer (build a good base first, worry about the details later) this is not all good advice. There is no good reason not to do stuff like curls - it doesn't take much time, it doesn't impede on recovery, it helps the core lifts and it helps to keep healthy elbows by providing stability in pressing movements. "Functional" training is a myth - a bigger muscle is a stronger muscle, and a stronger muscle is a more functional muscle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jeremie - but "a bigger muscle is a stronger muscle, and a stronger muscle is a more functional muscle" is definitely not accurate.  Bigger muscles aren't necessarily stronger, as body builders generally aren't the strongest, and stronger is definitely not more functional, as strengthening muscles in insolation does little to improve overall strength, and is actually the cause of a lot of injuries in atheletes

Comment: Science disagrees: [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11990746) & [2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25611080). The biggest predictor of strength is muscle size. You would have a hard time finding a pro bodybuilder who isn't strong, or a pro powerlifter who isn't huge. As for strengthening muscles in isolation, it does a lot to improve overall strength. Muscle is muscle - it doesn't care what implement you are using to stimulate it, it only cares that it is being stimulated.

Comment: Not to go off-topic, but neither of those articles support your conclusion (although, yes, all other things being equal, more muscle will mean more strength).  However, in context of the OP, who is not an olympic lifter, bicep curls will exercise a statistically insignificant amount of the anatomy.  Assuming a limited gym time, I would do an 100 pushups instead.  Exercises that use more muscles, build more muscles, raise metabolims further, and will actually be beneficial in a much more long-term manner.

Comment: @JérémieClos that's the biggest load of bullshit I've ever read...the biggest predictor of strength isn't even close to muscle size.

Comment: Care to correct my comment then? Because as far as powerlifting performance goes, it is extremely correlated with [overall muscle mass](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25611080) and [local muscle thickness](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11990746).